# IE-Specific Javascript Load Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm developing a web app using my local machine as a web server, and I'm seeing a problem on IE 10 that isn't popping-up on Firefox.

Loading the page under IE 10 gives me this error:

```
Message: Member not found.

Line: 14
Char: 26442
Code: 0
URI: [my-server]/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces
```

I can enter that URI into Firefox, and I get exactly the file I'm expecting.  Entering it in IE leads to a pair of questions ("Do you want to open or save jquery.js from [localhost-name]?", I answer "Open", "The publisher of jquery.js couldn't be verified.  Are you sure you want to run the program?", I answer "Open") ultimately culminating with:

```
Script: [local-filesystem-path]\jquery.js
Line: 14
Char: 1
Error: 'window' is undefined
Code: 800A1391
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

What's going on, and how do I make it stop?

---

**Edit:**  I'm fairly confident the latter half of this issue is a red herring.  That I can't load the script directly via IE is an annoying impediment to debugging, but I'm fairly confident the script IS getting loaded.  Meaning my real issue is IE throwing an error on jQuery.

Comment: Sounds like maybe IE is wrongly interpreting the MIME type of your jQuery file. You might want to try sending a `Content-Type: text/javascript` HTTP header from the server when serving that file.

Comment: Check that the file is being served with the correct content-type header? (application/javascript) - The second error message is the result of the (incorrectly) downloaded js file being executed by the windows script host and is a symptom of IE refusing to handle the file correctly.

Comment: @AlexW:  I'd love to try that.  Any idea how to edit the MIME types in Glassfish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I was running IE 10 in `Browser Mode: IE10 Compat View` and `Document Mode: IE7 standards`.  Switching the latter to `IE9 standards` made the problem go away.

Unfortunately, IE7 standards is apparently the default for that page, meaning the page defaults to its user interface not working, which isn't cool.  But that's another issue.

Comment: ... and the default is set in IE's Tools -> Compatibility View settings.  So at least I can make it go away locally.